# What types of words should one start with when creating a language from scratch?

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary

Is it more appropriate to start by creating nouns, verbs, general sentence structure words ie "the, a, or", or from somewhere else, when creating a language from scratch? Would it be more proper to start constructing the rules? Note that this is in general cases, when one isn't creating a language which explicitly rules out usage of any speech element.